# How can I centre the input between the buttons (bootstrap5)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to centre the input between the two buttons but I tried about everything I know and nothing works:(
Here's a picture of what it looks like right now, I want it to be smaller and inbetween (1 line).

[image]

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="card-footer">
  <div class="container d-flex">
    <div class="div mx-auto">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">-</a>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">+</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use `d-flex` class in your div container to enable flex layout

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="card-footer">
  <div class="container d-flex">
    <div class="d-flex mx-auto">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">-</a>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0" />
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">+</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `input-group` class in your div container.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Body -->
<div class="card-footer">
  <div class="container d-flex">
    <div class="input-group">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">-</a>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">+</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

in your css file:

.

```
.div.mx-auto{
    font-size:0;
}
.div.mx-auto a,
.div.mx-auto input{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: down-voted for following reasons: Code only answers can be considered low-quality. Without explaination they are hard to understand and as such to reproduce. The answer is missing a working [repro] as proof that it would solve the issue. The question is specifically labeld and titled with Bootstrap-5. A Bootstrap-solution should be chosen instead of custom CSS. Answer is technical incorrect and will not horizontally center as intended. Answer containing crucial typos within the code. Code could have been way shorter and easier.

Comment: Bootstrap is a css plugin. Why can't I use css? !!
The second point is that the code can not be shortened, if you do not know the reason for using the font size, just look at the html code, it has written each tag in one line. so space of 1 or 2 pixels is created between the tags and to remove it, the font-size of the parent must be set to zero.

Comment: And one more thing, css is so close to English that it needs no explanation, this is not a place to teach, but a place to fix bugs.

Comment: Bootstrap is not a CSS-Plugin, it is a Framework. The whole reason to use it, is not to write custom css or to minimize the usage. As you see in the 2 other answers, it is easily solvable with the framework itself. Adding custom CSS makes it more complicated and harder to fix issues as you have to check the influence of custom CSS aswell. SO is not a palce to just fix bugs. It is a library to find related issues and their fixes. A fix is worthless if the asker can't understand the solution.

Comment: @tacoshy only see tags. do you mean css?